# Unable to get value from single radio button in group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a yes / no radio button combination that both have the name 'Rigid' and what I'm trying to do is loop over them and grab the the value to match it to a database value. I can get the DB value ok but I don't seem to be able to get the radio button value.

Here's the JQuery I'm using:

```
var rigid = $("[name='Rigid']");
for (var j = 0; j < rigid.length; j++) {
    var selValueRigid = rigid[j].val();
    if (selValueRigid === data.Rigid) {
        rigid[j].prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        rigid[j].prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

And the generated HTML:

```
<label for="RigidYes">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>Yes
</label>
<input name="Rigid" id="RigidNo" value="F" checked="checked" type="radio">
<label for="RigidNo">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle active"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin inactive"></i>No
</label>
```

Comment: How about `$('[name="Rigid"][value="' + data.Rigid + '"]').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be done when I generate the HTML? I'm trying to change it once it's been loaded as I cant change the generation code - unless my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Yes. That will work after HTML is generated in is available in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use

```
$('[name="Rigid"][value="' + data.Rigid + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

---

However as per problem statement, use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get object at specified index.

```
var el = rigid.eq(j);
el.prop("checked", el.val() === data.Rigid);
```

Problem with your implementation is that `[]` will return you reference of native DOM element which doesn't have `.val()` and `.prop()` method.